# Why no auxiliary verb before "spoken"?

Tags: verbs, passive-voice, relative-pronouns, auxiliary-verbs, past-participles

> > Classical Latin was the literary standard dialect of Latin "**spoken** by higher socioeconomic classes, as opposed to the Vulgar Latin which is the generic term of the colloquial sociolects of Latin **spoken** across the Roman Empire by uneducated and less-educated classes.

Why there is no auxiliary verb before spoken?

Comment: What makes you think there should be one?

Comment: As in, "English is a Germanic languages which is spoken by million of people.", Here Germanic languages modifies English where "was" work as auxiliary verb for it, and is for"which was..."

Comment: I see. The two clauses beginning with "spoken" are past participial clauses functioning as modifiers of "Latin". As modifiers of nouns, they are very similar to relative clauses, cf. "... the literary standard dialect of Latin which was "spoken by higher socioeconomic classes ..."

Comment: @Billj- Ok, if this modifies the word "Latin "then why there is no comma as "...Latin, spoken by..."

Comment: Modifying participial phrases can be surrounded by commas, but they don't need to be. In this case they shouldn't be, because these are essential modifiers rather than optional modifiers. We need those modifiers to distinguish which Latin is which. Those commas would work if we were comparing Latin to German, for example.

Comment: @confusedguy Commas are not required. The past-participial modifiers are integrated into the structure of the noun phrase. A comma would imply that the information is supplementary (non-restrictive).

Comment: @Gary Batnovcan- But after applying comma "latin" still makes the same sense.

Answer (score 2):

Because such an auxiliary verb would cause problems.

If we compare "spoken Latin" to "written Latin", we're comparing two noun phrases.  We are not comparing clauses.  The participle "spoken" acts as a general modifier and does the same job here that an adjective typically does.  We're still comparing two noun phrases when we compare "Latin spoken by the elite" to "Latin spoken by the masses".

This is good.  The preposition "of" is happy to take a noun phrase as its object.  We can account for everything, and the sentence holds together.

In contrast, "Latin *is* spoken by the elite" is a complete independent clause.  It could be its own sentence.  It doesn't resemble a noun phrase at all.  The preposition "of" can't make any use of it.

With the auxiliary verbs in question, the preposition lacks an object and the independent clause lacks a transition.  We can't account for everything.  The sentence falls apart.

Comment: If "**which is**" added before **spoken** then sentence doesn't fall apart . Why?

Comment: This "which" is a relative pronoun.  That acts as the subject of the subordinate clause "which is spoken...." and it relates the clause to the preceding noun "Latin".  "Of" retains its object.  Adding that subordinating subject restores the connections that were lost when the clause stood independently.

Comment: In other words, you broke things by creating an independent clause, then fixed things by making the clause subordinate.